# Error when trying to load a my Aurelia custom element

Tags: aurelia, custom-element

I am a newbie with Aurelia and I am trying to create my first custom element. I am coming from Angular 1 and as far as I could understand, custom elements seems to be similar to Angular 1 directives.

So, I am getting the following error:
[image]

I have checked my template looking for some bad written html, but I can't find it. Does anyone have any idea? Code is shown below:

src/views/login/login.html

```
<template>
  <require from = "/resources/elements/login-form/login-form"></require>

  <h1>Login</h1>
  <login-form></login-form>
</template>
```

src/views/login/login.js

```
export class Login {}
```

src/resource/elements/login-form/login-form.html

```
<template>
  <div>Here's gonna be a form</div>
</template>
```

src/resource/elements/login-form/login-form.js

```
import {customElement} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('login-form')
export class LoginForm {

}
```

Comment: Aside from having spaces between `from` and the equal sign/attribute value, I don't see anything that stands out as wrong. I posted your code (minimally modified) to a gist.run page here: https://gist.run/?id=c79b2a31371441222f5827d5e74471bb

Comment: discovered the problem, my `from` attribute path was starting with slash `/`. Since I removed it, things got working. Thanks anyway for your comment @AshleyGrant!

Comment: also discovered that removing `@customElement`, things keep working.

Comment: @customElement is only required when you don't want to follow the naming convention of LoginForm class with login-form tag. Still, it might be a good idea to include it all the time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

src/resource/elements/login-form/login-form.js as below

```
export class LoginFormCustomElement {

}
```

This will work Aurelia framework having naming Conventions. When ever you are using as a custom element better to pass class name with end of CustomElement.